# Working with Microsoft Moles in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, moles, pex-and-moles

I have a visual studio 2010 solution (.Net3.5) that used Microsoft Moles for testing, I opened it in Visual Studio 2012 and I was able to build it, however I cannot run the tests from Visual Studio. The reason for this is that the Moles host adapter is not registered in vs2012.
So all test methods with [HostType("Moles")] fail to run with the following exception:

Message: UTA034:
CreateSite_MockProperties_Passes has invalid HostType attribute. A valid, registered host type must be specified.

Has anyone figured out how to register the Host adapter in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: 2012 lacks Moles support, likely to encourage use of the official release as the Fakes framework. Interesting question. I'll look into a solution.

Comment: Thanks Mike, unfortunately I can't afford the Ultimate SKU but really liked Moles in VS2010. I looked at another way of running Moles in VS2012 via External Tools and NUnit [link](http://joekirwindev.blogspot.ca/2012/09/microsoft-moles-with-visual-studio-2012.html). The MS Research team confirmed that they will release PEX for 2012 and I really liked using the 2 tools together in VS2010 IDE. As I'm actually working with .Net3.5 projects its more a case of registering the Moles Host Adapter I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its looking more optimistic for fans of the Moles framework.
As we know, its successor "Fakes and Stubs" was only available in VS2012 Ultimate SKU.

However Microsoft just announced that as of VS2012 Update 2, Premium SKU users will be able to use Fakes and Stubs. I'm happy with that!!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-vs2012-2.aspx

Comment: Yes! I saw it too! That's great! I didn't have time to fiddle with it anyway, but I'm happy that I didn't waste my time since it is here now.

Comment: When I wanted to use it I was thinking about Faking out such native Printing, File or Network or other functionality, which I don't have a shim library for (since .NET's classes can be so handy that you dont' need any layer on top of that). That usage is fine I guess, but in general someone should be careful to design testable code.

Comment: When I saw the "Add Fakes Assembly" in the context menu of an Assembly Reference, I thought I've found a glitch in the 'Matrix'. It's way better that it is not a bug but it is officially supported now.

Answer (score 0):

We have to figure out how to install that Host adapter in Visual Studio 2012!

Comment: If I were going to try to look into this further I would look at understanding how to build a custom test host adapter in VS2010 and then how to build one in VS2012, observing registration differences and also the different interface requirements. 

Here are some links that may be useful to you:

Writing a Visual Studio 2012 Unit Test Adapter - [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/31/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter.aspx)

Creating and Using Host Adapters (VS2005-VS2010) - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166558(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I'll dig into this if I'll have time. Another idea: maybe I can disect a VS2011 beta how is it in it. If the interfaces didn't change, we can just grab the necessary dlls, put them into the right place and do some registration work in registry and VS and some configuration. Or even maybe some some VS2012 betas/RCs. But I'm afraid those are expired now.

Comment: I just don't know if a Host adapter is enough. Surely it'll allow running of tests, once everything is in place. More specifically: how will we add the functionality which allows generation of the Moles assemblies (when you right click and there's the 'Add Moles assemblies')? Is that provided by the Host adapter too? I'll only have time for this only after the end of December.